# Rewrite block class for specific site only

Tags: blocks, frontend, overrides

I have two sites in a multi-site Magento EE installation. I must rewrite the `_getHtml` function of the `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu` class for just one of the sites. Is it possible to target this rewrite to a single site, or am I going about this wrong?

The `config.xml` for the overwriting Page module is as follows:

```
<!-- Foo used as module name for posting purposes -->
<config>
    <modules>
        <Foo_Page>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <depends><!-- no dependencies --></depends>
        </Foo_Page>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <page>
                <rewrite>
                    <html_topmenu>Foo_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu</html_topmenu>
                </rewrite>
            </page>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Currently this rewrite is affecting both sites' `topmenu` blocks. I would like to use the default `_getHtml` function for one site, and use my rewrite for the other. Is this possible in a multi-site setup?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way of doing this would be in your function to check what store you are in and then choosing either your new code or simply calling the parent function.

But you could also change the code from a rewrite to use either `page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_after` or `page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before` and then when you are on a site that you want to change the html then you can do this via an observer.